# How to package javafx application with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, javafx, package, java-14

I have javafx application build with gradle and i'm using external library apache poixml
and need to create jar for it and it fail to run when using the poixml classes
sample project for what i tried on github : https://github.com/IslamAssem/HelloFX-Gradle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you use a seperately downloaded OpenJFX14 jar and included it into your Build path.

I would add JavaFX to your dependecies via Gradle..

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'


    // here starts JavaFX
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx:14'

    compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-base:14'
    compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:14'
    compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:14'
    compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:14'
    compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-swing:14'
    compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-media:14'
    compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-web:14'
}
```

Then I would recommend that your Main is not in a class that extends from Application.

You should create a Launcher.

```java
public class Launcher{

   public static void main(String[] args){
     Application.launch(HelloFX.class,args);
   }
}
```

And to Build a Jar with JavaFX...

Add this to your build.gradle:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'your.main.package.Launcher' // replace with you main class
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

This should to the deal.

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly but the generated jar is very big it's about 50mb and all i have i aprogram that print text on label

Comment: @Islam Assem the reason could be, thet you include Modules You don't need. For example Jafaxf.media etc. Just include what you really need. Also apache Poi is really big by itself.

Comment: Ok thanks,i'll start learning proguard to get red of these classes